# Incrementing date with delayed function inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't really know what to ask so please spare me with this problem I'm having.

I wanted to get the currently selected date of input `input=date`, then loop and call function `task()` to do something with the date. I also want to add delay to the loop.

```
$('#loopDays').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var numberOfDays = 10;
    
    let date = new Date($('#sDate').val()); //(1) get the current selected date, or the default selected date. This is input [type=date].
    
    for (let i=0; i < numberOfDays; i++) { //(2) lets say loop for 10 days.
        task(date, i); //(3) do something with the date and delayed 1 seconds before processing the next date.
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); //(4) add day to date.
    }
        
    //here is the task where I want to process the date, for now I just want to print it into console to make sure I'm getting the expected result.
    function task(date, x){ 
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('LOOP#' + x + ': ' + date.getFullYear()+'-'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+date.getDate());
        }, 1000 * x); //delayed 1 seconds.
    }
});
```

Let's say the current date of input or the default value is `10/08/2021` which is `August 10, 2021`. Why I am getting the following result:

```
LOOP#0: 2021-8-20
LOOP#1: 2021-8-20
LOOP#2: 2021-8-20
LOOP#3: 2021-8-20
LOOP#4: 2021-8-20
LOOP#5: 2021-8-20
LOOP#6: 2021-8-20
LOOP#7: 2021-8-20
LOOP#8: 2021-8-20
LOOP#9: 2021-8-20
```

Instead of:

```
LOOP#0: 2021-8-10
LOOP#1: 2021-8-11
LOOP#2: 2021-8-12
LOOP#3: 2021-8-13
LOOP#4: 2021-8-14
LOOP#5: 2021-8-15
LOOP#6: 2021-8-16
LOOP#7: 2021-8-17
LOOP#8: 2021-8-18
LOOP#9: 2021-8-19
```

What's the problem with the logic? Can anyone help me get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast fixed for the problem is use below code instead of `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);`:

```
date = new Date(date.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000));//add one day
```

But if you insist on using `setDate` try this one:

```
var newDate = new Date(date);
newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
date = newDate
```

Snippet for **solution 1**

```js
$('#loopDays').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var numberOfDays = 10;

    let date = new Date("2021-8-10"); //(1) get the current selected date, or the default selected date. This is input [type=date].

    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfDays; i++) { //(2) lets say loop for 10 days.
         task(date, i); //(3) do something with the date and delayed 1 seconds before processing the next date.
        date = new Date(date.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000));
    }

    //here is the task where I want to process the date, for now I just want to print it into console to make sure I'm getting the expected result.
    function task(date, x) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('LOOP#' + x + ': ' + date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate());
        }, 1000 * x); //delayed 1 seconds.
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="loopDays">click me</div>
```

Snippet for **solution 2**: (using `setDate`)

```js
 $('#loopDays').on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var numberOfDays = 10;

     let date = new Date("2021-8-10");//(1) get the current selected date, or the default selected date. This is input [type=date].

     for (let i = 0; i < numberOfDays; i++) { //(2) lets say loop for 10 days.
         task(date, i); //(3) do something with the date and delayed 1 seconds before processing the next date.

         var newDate = new Date(date);
         newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
         date = newDate;
     }

     //here is the task where I want to process the date, for now I just want to print it into console to make sure I'm getting the expected result.
     function task(date, x) {
         setTimeout(function () {
             console.log('LOOP#' + x + ': ' + date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate());
         }, 1000 * x); //delayed 1 seconds.
     }
 });
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="loopDays">click me</div>
```

Comment: @Papilion Has your problem been solved? let me know if there is a problem

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code instead of (3), (4) steps.

```
...

for (let i=0; i < numberOfDays; i++) { 
    task(new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() , date.getDate() + i), i);
}

...
```

or

```
for (let i=0; i < numberOfDays; i++) {
    task(new Date(date), i); 
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); //(4) add day to date.
}
```